# Label NSMutableAttributedString programmatically swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have to make sure that I can click on the word "Privacy" in order to open a web link. I tried with the suggestions that I found but they are old things and they do not seem to work anymore .. I do not know how I can solve the problem

```
    private lazy var firstTermDescriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    let firstTermsMessage = "I Agree to the License Terms and Privacy Policy"
    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Privacy")
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/58446596&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1528787597335000&usg=AFQjCNEPkofPxSm7TDRMvxjOjCz5cio27w", range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 7))

    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.text = firstTermsMessage
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular)
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true
    return label
}()
```

[image]

Comment: Where you are setting attributed string?

Comment: @karthikeyan "    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Privacy")
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/58446596&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1528787597335000&usg=AFQjCNEPkofPxSm7TDRMvxjOjCz5cio27w", range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 7))"

Comment: Don't use `UILabel`, use `UITextView`. Cf here at 2:00 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/221/ the part "Chosing the Right Control".

Comment: @Larme ok I replaced, how can I add the link to the word? the "attributedString" method seems to keep on not seeing me ..

Comment: Textview.attributedText = attributedString, not .text

Comment: @Larme oh thanks I do! now I have to try to understand better how to make just a clickable word (because now I have the whole sentence clickable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to Swift 4

Add this extension to your project

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    public func setAsLink(textToFind:String, linkURL:String) -> Bool {

        let foundRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind)
        if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
//            self.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: linkURL, range: foundRange)
            self.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.link: URL(string: linkURL)!], range: foundRange)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Change your like below:

```
let firstTermsMessage = "I Agree to the License Terms and Privacy Policy"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:firstTermsMessage)
        let linkWasSet = attributedString.setAsLink(textToFind: "Privacy", linkURL: "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/58446596&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1528787597335000&usg=AFQjCNEPkofPxSm7TDRMvxjOjCz5cio27w")

        if linkWasSet {
            // adjust more attributedString properties
        }
        lableAtt.attributedText = attributedString
        lableAtt.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
lableAtt.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapOnLabel(_:))))


 @objc func handleTapOnLabel(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let text = lableAtt.attributedText?.string else {
            return
        }

        if let range = text.range(of:"terms") {
//            goToTermsAndConditions()
        } else if let range = text.range(of: "Privacy"){
            print(range)
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/58446596&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1528787597335000&usg=AFQjCNEPkofPxSm7TDRMvxjOjCz5cio27w")!, options: [:])
        }
    }
```

Comment: @StefanoOddone if it is not opening in safari . what is the error in the console

Comment: @Vinodh I have to use "NSMutableAttributedString" and not this procedure. I also tried this as suggested, but it gives me too many conflicts and resolving them crashes the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re up for using a bit of third-party code, `TTTAttributedLabel` is a widely-used “drop-in replacement for UILabel” that lets you embed a link easily!

You can find it here: https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/