# Find Touched characters in UILabel with attributedString without using TextStorage

Tags: swift, uilabel

I've been investigating ways to find hashtags/mentions/... in UILabel.
All Libs out there are just doing fine, but when it comes to RTL languages like Persian and texts getting too long in UITableView the scrolling becomes lagging and Consumes CPU up to 50% each time this row is visited. I figured out that all these libs are using textStorage somehow, and by removing it and using a cache method the lag is all gone and list scrolls smoothly, but the problem is that without textStorage its not possible (I can't find a way) to find which character is touched by the user. so if I solve this, my problem with RTL languages is solved, so here's the Question: we've got a UIlabel and a CGPoint how to find characters touched?

currently using this modified method by ContextLabel Library:

```
fileprivate func linkResult(at location: CGPoint) -> LinkResult? {
    var fractionOfDistance: CGFloat = 0.0
    let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: &fractionOfDistance)
    if characterIndex <= textStorage?.length {
        if let linkResults = contextLabelData?.linkResults {
            for linkResult in linkResults {
                let rangeLocation = linkResult.range.location
                let rangeLength = linkResult.range.length
                
                let rect = self.boundingRect(forCharacterRange: linkResult.range)
                if(rect?.contains(location))!
                {
                    return linkResult
                }
                                 
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

which boundingRect is

```
func boundingRect(forCharacterRange range: NSRange) -> CGRect? {
    
    guard let attributedText = attributedText else { return nil }
    
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size:CGSize(width:self.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    
    var glyphRange = NSRange()
    
    // Convert the range for glyphs.
    layoutManager.characterRange(forGlyphRange: range, actualGlyphRange: &glyphRange)
    
    return layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, in: textContainer)
}
```

and linkResults are those hashtags, mentions, url... that are previously found and now its going to search through them , this always returns nil when textStorage is removed

UPDATE: its working now with current methods for English Text no matter how long but not for RTL yet

Comment: Why not using `UITextView` for that instead of `UILabel`. Cf my comment and the link there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793833/label-nsmutableattributedstring-programmatically-swift-4#comment88594592_50793833

Comment: @Larme there are more that 10 cells designed with UILabel with complex constraints so can't just switch easily , but I've already tried two good libs with UITextView and they were laggy too with RTL languages and some had problems with Dynamic height in UITableView so I came up customizing one of the libs for my need and clicking is the only problem